# Getting no module named TF error while running Jupyter cell

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm, jupyter-notebook

I have installed all the dependencies, added jupyter and TensorFlow in python interpreter of pycharm. It still gives error on execution:

> No module named TF.

It does not give any error while importing tensorflow.

Comment: how did you import tensorflow? E.g. import tensorflow as TF?

Comment: yes , import tensorflow as tf not capital TF

Comment: well, Python is case-sensitive. Do you have a "TF" lurking somewhere in your code where you meant "tf"?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing tensorflow in the standard way (capitalization matters here):

`import tensorflow as tf`

and then search for all instances of "TF" in your code  (on unix, `grep TF *.py`) or using the case-sensitive search in your editor.